# Levi-Civita connection in Poincaré gauge theory

Tags: gravity

I'm reading physics paper from J.Nester "Can torsion be treated as just another tensor field?"

We are considering generic Lagrangian in Poincaré gauge theory and orthonormal coframe is denoted as $\vartheta^\alpha$ 1-form.
Levi-Civita connection 1-form is given as:

$
2\Gamma_{\alpha\beta} = −e_\alpha\rfloor\mathrm{d}\vartheta_\beta + e_\beta\rfloor\mathrm{d}\vartheta_\alpha + (e_\beta\rfloor(e_\alpha\mathrm{d}\vartheta_\gamma))\vartheta^\gamma,
$
where $\rfloor$ is a sign for contraction.

How can this be derived?

Comment: How is $\rfloor$ defined and what is meant by the juxtaposition $(e_\alpha\mathrm{d}\vartheta_\gamma)$? But in any case you can try writing it out in coordinates or using the Cartan Structure equation with torsion=0.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be derived by "solving" the structure equation for the vanishing torsion, i.e. $d\vartheta^a=-\Gamma^a{}_b\wedge \vartheta^b$. Do the interior contraction of this as prescribed and you will actually see that this is true. Of course, you can reformulate this by using the structure 2-forms since $C^a=\tfrac{1}{2}C^a{}_{bc}\vartheta^b\wedge \vartheta^c=-d\vartheta^a$. I am not sure though about Nester's convention regarding the position of indices, so you will have to check this for yourself.